# no history when chrome reopen closed tab with extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm using crxMouse and one of it's function is reopen closed tab.

Then I noticed that the opened tabs don't have history.

So, is there any chance for the same result as original one with chrome extension?

I can't find any related description in chrome's tab API docs.

thanks <3

Comment: It probably means the extension simply opens a new tab with an old URL, it doesn't actually reopen the tab. I would try using chrome.sessions API instead.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sessions

I modified the source code of crxMouse myself which could raise legal problems

in ./js/messaging.js  you can find a function named G_reclosedtab() and replace its content with

```
chrome.sessions.restore()
```

and modify the manifest.json  add  'sessions' into 'permissions' array